# Javascript scope/this

Tags: javascript, this

How come when I do:

```
function Dog(){
   this.firstName = 'scrappy';
}
```

Dog.firstName is undefined?

However then I can do:

```
Dog.firstName = 'scrappy';
```

And now Dog.firstName returns 'scrappy'?

Comment: Why did you delete your question and post it again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441586/this-keyword-function-scope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How come when I do ... `Dog.firstName` is undefined?

Because...

- ... `Dog` is never called, so the line `this.firstName = 'scrappy';` is never executed and ...
- ... even if you call the function, `this` probably won't refer to the function `Dog`. You *can* call it in a way that `this` refers to `Dog`, but that is rather unusual . [How the value of `this` is determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) [has been explained extensively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

> However then I can do ... And now Dog.firstName returns 'scrappy'?

Functions are just objects, so you can assign any property to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Dog()` function is just the constructor, so you're calling `firstname` on the constructor rather than an instance of it. This isn't defined just by virtue of it being defined on the returned objects, they're totally separate things. However, because you can augment functions with fields, you were able to assign a value to dog.firstName anyway.

First, let me demonstrate the difference between a constructor and an instance:

```
function Dog() {
    this.firstName = 'scrappy';
}

Dog.firstname; // undefined on the constructor

Dog.prototype; // defined on constructor, returns an empty object

var myDog = new Dog();

myDog.firstname; // defined on instance, returns 'scrappy'

myDog.prototype; // undefined on instance
```

As you can see, a constructor (a function that returns an object) is a totally different thing to the object it returns, and has totally different fields as a result. What you were seeing when you got Dog.firstname to return 'scrappy' was the result of adding a new field to the constructor. This is doable, but remember, adding a field to the constructor will not add the same field to the constructed. Consider:

```
Dog.someNewProperty = 'whatever';

var myDog = new Dog();

Dog.someNewProperty; // 'whatever'
myDog.someNewProperty; // undefined
```